# Can't use the command I want on GitHub

Tags: git-bash, github-for-windows

I have uploaded a function to my GitHub account and this is the first time I do that. I wonder how I can use GitHub's command line. I want to delete all the history but not the original repository. I've got `git push origin +master` as answer after some searching with Google.

When I enter this command in the command line on GitHub and hit enter, it starts to search. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: well, start by cloning the repository to your computer, and use git directly to execute commands

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work either :/ I have syncronized my repositories to the Windows software and clicked me in to the commits. I have then choosen Powershell and opened that up (sorry for my bad english but I'm tired tonight) and entered the command. I'm getting some messages that everything is 100% but it didn't do anything - my commit history are still there!

Comment: I'm afraid you need to learn more on how git works, this nice book is a must-read: http://git-scm.com/book

Comment: Thanks. I'll start there :)